# MX Record Query fails

Tags: c#, interop, dns, unmanaged

I'm a managed code guy, so when I interop with unmanaged code, and it doesn't work as advertised, I get twitchy. Can someone explain to me why this would come back with no MX records, when a command line `nslookup` works?

```
[DllImport("dnsapi", EntryPoint = "DnsQuery_W", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern int DnsQuery([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)]ref string pszName, QueryTypes wType, QueryOptions options, int aipServers, ref IntPtr ppQueryResults, int pReserved);

string domain = "HomeTechnologySolutions.com";
int num1 = DnsQuery(ref domain, QueryTypes.DNS_TYPE_MX, QueryOptions.DNS_QUERY_BYPASS_CACHE, 0, ref ptr1, 0);
if (num1 != 0)
{
    throw new Win32Exception(num1)
}
```

The error code that comes back means "No records found for given DNS query"

The kick in the pants is that this is the first domain I have found that fails this test, but I am told it happens "OFTEN". ( no one can define often for me yet, but I am working on that)

Anyway, when I perform a nslookup through the command prompt, I get back:

```
> set type=mx
> hometechnologysolutions.com
Server:  dhcp.removedtoprotectedtheguilty.com
Address:  10.0.0.9

hometechnologysolutions.com
        primary name server = ns1.streetsimple.com
        responsible mail addr = hostmaster.streetsimple.com
        serial  = 11
        refresh = 900 (15 mins)
        retry   = 600 (10 mins)
        expire  = 86400 (1 day)
        default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)
```

Comment: nope - there's still no MX records returned by nslookup...

Comment: and still none from here either.  There simply *aren't* any MX records on that domain.

Comment: Then howcome email works then?

Comment: because in the absence of MX records any A record present is treated as equivalent to an MX record with priority 0.

Comment: Where can I find documentation to back that up? ( Looks like your right, but I need doc's to prove it to the powers that be )

Comment: Never, mind, I found it. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't get any `MX` records returned for that particular domain name when using 'dig' from here either.

The 'nslookup' results that you're quoting there are from the domain's `SOA` record and don't include any `MX` records.  The `SOA` record is returned in the "authority" section of the DNS response, even if there's no records for the specific question you asked.

In the absence of `MX` records, mail transfer agents (MTAs) will treat the `A` record for the host as an `MX` record with priority 0 and attempt to make an SMTP connection to that address instead.

See section 5.1 of [RFC 5321](http://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=5321).  Note that although this is a very recent RFC, this behaviour also existed in previous versions of the SMTP specification.